# No module named 'en_core_web_sm'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, nlp, spacy

I am trying to use the en_core_web_sm in Jupyter Notebook.

I have tried to use: conda install en_core_web_sm but It did not work how can I install this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`en_core_web_sm` is a language model provided by SpaCy. First, you have to [install SpaCy](https://spacy.io/usage), then try this snippet:

```
import spacy
from spacy.lang.en.examples import sentences 

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp(sentences[0])
print(doc.text)
for token in doc:
    print(token.text, token.pos_, token.dep_)
```

Answer (score 1):

!python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
Please try this and hope it works

Comment: In line with [the spaCy documentation here](https://spacy.io/usage), in a running Jupyter `.ipynb` file you should run `%pip install spacy` and restart the kernel **before trying to run that line posted by Himanshu Chatterjee**. `%pip install` is a convenient & better way to do `pip install` in a running Jupyter `.ipynb` file because the magic version of the command insures the installation occurs in the correct environment where the kernel is running that back the running Jupyter `.ipynb` file. **Use `%conda install -c conda-forge spacy` though if you are using Anaconda/conda** because ...

Comment: <continued> you choose that as your primary package manager when installing Anaconda/conda and you only want to resort to using `pip` if there is no conda recipe.

Comment: And **using `%run -m spacy download en_core_web_sm` in place of that line posted** by Himanshu Chatterjee  is more consistent with best practices in modern Jupyter. Then you'll be ready to run the first three lines of the code block in Silent Cloud's in your notebook, or all of it for that matter.